# Projector associated with an eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reading a research paper and I can't quite get what a projector associated with an eigenvector is.

[extract from the research paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOF13.png)

where $\Lambda$ is an nxn matrix.

Can anyone please help. Many thanks.

Comment: "Upside down V" is capital Lambda. You can write it in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) by typing `$\Lambda$`.

Comment: Thanks, updated

Comment: That image is nigh unreadable. Please at least crop it so that it doesn’t get scaled down to nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an eigenvector there is an associated eigenspace (spanned by the vector). The corresponding projector is the orthogonal  projection onto that subspace. If you take your eigenvector unitary say $u$ ) then the matrix of the projector is $P=uu^T$

Comment: Many thanks for this. Does $P=uu^T$  only holds true for eigenvectors or does it holds true for any vectors?

Comment: Also, does the definition of projector of an eigenvector $P = uu^T$ applies to the actual eigenvector too rather than the eigenvector unitary? ie. is this also true $P = vv^T$ where v = actual eigenvector?

Comment: If the eigenvector is not unitary then you have to divide by the square of its norm in the formula and yes this all makes sense for any vector it does not have to be an eigenvector. It is especially relevant for eigenvector because of the spectral decomposition.